# Join queries are not working as expected when trying to compare a count result with a value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm learnin `SQL` from a book and i'm trying to do some exercices on `join queries`.The only problem that i'm facing is that all of my join `queries` are not working while they seem well

```
students(student_id,student_names,student_age)
courses_students(course_id,student_id)
courses(course_id,course_schedule,course_room,teacher_id)
teachers(teacher_id,teacher_names)
```

The query is "which courses have more than 5 students enrolled?"

Here is what i've done :

```
SELECT course_name,
       count
  (SELECT count(*)
   FROM courses) AS COUNT
FROM students,
     courses,
     courses_students
WHERE students.student_id=courses_students.student_id,
      courses.course_id=courses_students.course_id
  AND COUNT > 5
```

And the other one is what are the names of students enrolled in at least 2 courses scheduled for the same hours

My query :

```
SELECT student_name,
       schedule
FROM students,
     courses,
     courses_students
WHERE students.student_id=courses_students.student_id,
      courses.course_id=courses_students.course_id
  AND COUNT > 2
```

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: For the first query the names of courses that have more the 5 students registered and the 2nd query the names of students who are enrolled in at least 2 courses that have the same schedule

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 0):

In this inner query:

```
(SELECT count(*)
  FROM courses) AS COUNT
```

you need to narrow down what is included in the `COUNT`. As it is, it is selecting all items in the `courses` table. The inner query does not know about the restrictions in the outer query. Try adding a `where` clause in this inner query. You might need to add table aliases to uniquely refer to the correct `courses` table, so there is no ambiguity whether it is referring to the `courses` table in the inner query or the outer query.

And, as noted in other answers, this is not the best way to structure joins.

Answer (score 0):

stackoverflow is actually not a site to do homework, but as you already have given a try to solve the task, here is a solution for question number one:

```
      SELECT cs.course_id
        FROM courses_students cs
  INNER JOIN students s
          ON cs.course_id = s.course_id
    GROUP BY cs.course_id
      HAVING count(*) > 5
```

Read about the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clause - nice way to solve some problems.

Question number 2 could be solved like this:

```
      SELECT student_names
        FROM students s 
  INNER JOIN courses_students cs
          ON cs.student_id = s.student_id
  INNER JOIN (    
              SELECT course_id
                FROM courses c
            GROUP BY course_schedule
              HAVING count(*) > 1
             ) sub
             ON sub.course_id = cs.course_id
```

The `INNER JOIN` with the subquery is selecting courses which are scheduled at the same time (having the same course_schedule).
As the other tables are "connected" with `INNER JOIN`s, we will finally just have the subset of students which are participating one of those courses.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you are required to define `joins` explicitly. Unlike `Oracle` it can't handle joins with sign of `=`.

```
SELECT course_name,
       count
  (SELECT count(*)
   FROM courses) AS COUNT
FROM students 
     INNER JOIN courses  on courses.course_id=courses_students.course_id
     INNER JOIN courses_students  on students.student_id=courses_students.student_id
WHERE  COUNT(*) > 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to aggregage by course and then assert the number of students:

```
SELECT
    c.course_name,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM courses c
INNER JOIN courses_students cs
    ON c.course_id = cs.course_id
INNER JOIN students s
    ON cs.student_id = s.student_id
GROUP BY
    c.course_name
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 5;
```